# printable view for record detail page in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I want a printable view of any object's record detail page(as in classic).I tried using window.print using custom button,link and actions but the problem is that if we have multiple pages then it overwrites on the header.first page is fine but from 2nd page it overwrites from the header part.I also tried opening the detail page from apex page using window.open and then printing using window.print but it doesn't seem to work.It prints a blank page instead.